# Realm delete and insert transaction in one callback

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

There are a lot of projects, where we update our recyclerview after transacion. But i faced with situation when I need to clean and add new data, and after that get one callback (for updating recyclerview only one time, not twice) using OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener. I want to add this transaction to rxjava emitter.onNext but I can't understand is it possible or not?

Example from site:

```
puppies.addChangeListener(new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Dog>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<Dog> results, OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {
       Emitter.onNext(results);
    }
});
```

When i get Observable i start Recyclerview method  - notifydatasetchanged(). Recyclerview subscribes on Realm model. For example I get new data from net and I need to delete data from realm and then insert new data. I get two observables and notifydatasetchanged() works twice, but i need only one time. That is why I must union two transaction in one.

Comment: I have zero clue what you are asking :D

Comment: I added information.

Comment: Or maybe you could just not ignore the `OrderedCollectionChangeSet` you're getting?

Comment: I can ignore but It doesn't help. Because I can do 3 transaction: 1) only delete 2) only insert 3) delete and insert!  I don't know in OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener what transaction i have in the current moment that is why i send all transaction. I can't pack "delete and insert" in one Observable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do anything you want in a single transaction, and the change set will be evaluated accordingly. I don't know what you mean by "only delete" and "only insert".

Comment: Ok. When i do operarion deleteAllFromRealm() and then insert(Collection) I get two events in Listener. But I need update RecyclerView only one time. Do you understand? At the same moment, I can't ignore deleteAllFromRealm() event because possible situation when I haven't data and user must see empty list. These are two different situation.

Comment: Why not do them in one transaction then?

Comment: It,s imposible. i don't know what type of transaction only deleteAllFromRealm() or maybe deleteAllFromRealm()+insert(Collection). How to split them correct? I can save infromation about deleteAllFromRealm() but what next? And how long to store information about deleteAllFromRealm() operation?

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/c4ec2e0df75aea24df2e67b2135909198f05a789/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.java#L52-L77 ?

Comment: Because it's bad for user experience.  User musn't see empty list, only the full list If we have  deleteAllFromRealm()+insert(Collection) operation,  without an intermediate stage ( deleteAllFromRealm() stage). Or the screen flickers out (data update twice on the screen)

Comment: Then run it in one transaction.

Comment: How? Can you show example? Ok, i know about all different transaction, but i know nothing about sequence of transaction. That means I can't merge two transaction because I am not sure that two successive transaction will be in one stage may be it will be two different transaction.

Comment: I spoke above merge transaction in OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener. if you told about two transaction in one transaction block for example "begin and commit" this scheme doesn't work listener works twice.